# How to scroll to the bottom of the page when at the bottom of the page (with a div)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a simple chat widget that will automatically load data from a different file, and stay at the bottom of the page unless the user has scrolled up at all. So far I have the loading working but the scrolling has not worked yet. I have tried several different answers on SO as well as many other places, non of them have worked. Also, I am relatively new to JavaScript.

Here is the code i am using, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>BennerBot v0.7 ~ Chat</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resource/layout.css" media="screen" />
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function (){
        $('#load').load('output.html?_=' +Math.random()).fadeIn("slow");
        $("#load").attr({ scrollTop: $("#load").attr("scrollHeight") });
     }, 1000);
    </script>
 </head>

 <body>
    <div id="load" style="overflow:auto"> </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Here is an example of the file that i am using:

```
 <center><h1>Welcome to BennerBot</h1>Version 0.7</center>
 <img src=./resource/OutputLogo.png>08:48 <span style='color:#ff0000'>BennerBot</span>: Sucessfully Connected to Twitch<br>
 <img src=./resource/OutputLogo.png>08:48 <span style='color:#ff0000'>BennerBot</span>: Sucessfully Connected to Hitbox<br>
 <img src=./resource/OutputLogo.png>08:56 <span style='color:#ff0000'>BennerBot</span>: all the infromations<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chakrei/5qrh9rqf/). This may answer your problem

```
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop : $('.last').offset().top
},3000);
```

All you have to do is add scrolling action at documents ready function.

Comment: Thank you for the response, but i am using a dynamic div where the content is being added dynamically. This dose not work eather